# Ideas for OpenSource FORUMS in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, forums

I am in the process of collecting ideas for building an opensource FORUMS based on ASP.net framework.

I have choosen ASP.NET MVC with Jquery as the tool to develop this.

You can add your points or add some depth to any of the above feature.

Answer (score 0):

Have you actually tried googling this?

[Google](http://www.google.com.au/#hl=en&safe=off&q=asp.net-mvc+open+source+forum+framework&meta=&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=&fp=1d433b24f5b1b711)

[ASP.Net](http://wiki.asp.net/page.aspx/388/aspnet-open-source-projects/)

Just to name two places.

Answer (score 0):

Why reinvent the wheel? [OpenForum](http://openforum.codeplex.com/) is an open-source forum for ASP.NET MVC. You could use that or even contribute back to it.

Comment: lol ... as good a reason as any, I suppose. At least give OpenForum a look - might be some ideas in there worth "borrowing".

Comment: Looks like a link to an archive, so assume its no longer maintained? Any newer/updated ones?

Answer (score 0):

You can't miss this one on your list. **http://www.yetanotherforum.net/**

[Features' list on their website](http://www.yetanotherforum.net/features.aspx)

[image]
<sub>(source: [yetanotherforum.net](http://www.yetanotherforum.net/images/YAF_SS_F.jpg))</sub>

**[PhpBB](https://www.phpbb.com/)** is also very widely used forum.

[Features' list on their website](https://www.phpbb.com/about/features/?sid=3b8335963a6ca7a3309eb84e9d391d6d)

[image]
<sub>(source: [pegasoft.cz](http://www.pegasoft.cz/img_novinky/new_velka/cpanel-phpbb-message-board.jpg))</sub>